# Задача на рекурсию

Tags: c#, рекурсия

Требуется с помощью рекурсии определить можно ли из массива 1..N, в котором лежать целые неотрицательные числа, получить сумму K.
Никак не могу найти алгоритм для определения возможности получить число из суммы других чисел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не надо суммировать, вычитайте

```
public bool CangetSumOfK(int[] data, int k, int index = 0)
{
    if (k == 0) return true;
    if (k < 0) return false;
    if (index >= data.Length) return false;

    return CangetSumOfK(data, k, index+1) 
    || CangetSumOfK(data, k - data[index], index+1); 
}
```

Как использовать

```
var data = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};    
Console.WriteLine(CangetSumOfK(data, 11));
Console.WriteLine(CangetSumOfK(data, 110));
```

Вывод

```
True
False
```